# How to connect to DynamoDb v2 with boto?

Tags: python, amazon-dynamodb

I am not new to Python, I am not new to nosql, I am not even new to AWS, however I am 100% new to Boto and dynamodb, I completely understand everything I have read about DynamoDb, except how to setup a connection to the service from my local dev environment.

I tried a few things, but it fails, and when I search the web I keep getting v1 stuff.

Can somebody please give me a link or a type up something that succinctly explains how to connect to the DynamoDB v2 Interface?

Comment: I feel your frustration, but you need to tell us what "few things" you've tried and what went wrong so we can work out where the problem is.

Comment: As it says in the cryptic comments in their otherwise succinct and easily understood documentation, I tried setting environment variables using the quoted names they give. I would love to set up the mysterious config file that is mentioned in said comments, but alas, no example is given. v1 seems easy to grasp - you create a connection and you route other Dynamo params through it. The docs on connecting to the v2 interface are mysterious and vague like the distant sounds of ships passing in the dark starless night. Also how did someone with a rep of 7 edit my post? Another mystery.

Comment: @Basic, I have had a long week.

Comment: Low-rep users can propose edits. If they're approved by a number of higher-rep users, the changes are applied. In this instance, you approved the change yourself: http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/7913241

Answer (score 1):

Found this yesterday, a simple interface to DynamoDB for Python:

https://github.com/eykd/duo

```
import duo

# Connect
db = duo.DynamoDB(key='aws_key', secret='aws_secret')

table = duo.DynamoDB['my_hashkey_table']
item = table['new-item']

# Get
print item['foo']

# Set
item['bar'] = 'bar'
item.put()
```